# Laravel error : email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am getting a larval 4.2 error : email , I never seen this one before

my model : /User/Setting.php ( this is the line causing error)

```
 \User::find($user_id)->fill($update)->save();
```

Does anyone know what that error means?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably means that `email` is not in the `$fillable` array of your model.
When you want to [mass assign attributes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment) to your model you have to whitelist the attributes that should be fillable.
Just add this in your model and you should be good to go:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    // [...]

    protected $fillable = ['foo', 'bar', 'email'];
}
```

(instead of `foo` and `bar` add the other attributes you want to pass to `fill()`)

Comment: I dont understand you what you mean fillable array?

Comment: where do I add that in ? which file?

Comment: In the `User` model. I updated the question with a bit a longer explanation. Also make sure to hit up the link that leads to the official documentation

Comment: I see you point but I have couple of models that I use fill() so for each models I have to add protected $fillable = ['foo', 'bar', 'email']; right? to make fill work?

Comment: That is correct. The reason is that it acts as protection mechanism when passing user input directly (`fill(Input::all())` for example)

Comment: the thing is I am moving from larval 3.2 to larval 4.2 , I am not sure how larval 3.2 used to work with fill() do you know?

Comment: yes I don't think you need to specify $fillable variable for version 3.2 , thats why now I m getting that error